# Building 'Responsive' Websites for Desktops/iPads/iPhones/Mobiles

Tags: php, jquery, iphone, mobile

I currently manage a few websites.  I am not new to building a website for mobile devices and but I have a question.  My friend has bought a template that seems to 'build' the website on the fly when the user accesses it from a mobile device.

The only reason I speculate such a thing is because when he updates his website, he'll just update the HTML as normal.  See the only method I know of is to build two completely different websites, one for mobile, one for desktops.

How does the template do this?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show some code, or point to the product in question

Comment: This is an awfully broad question. Have you looked at things like http://www.jquerymobile.com or http://www.getskeleton.com?

Comment: One of the techniques these type of systems can use is replacing the CSS with versions that are more small screen friendly. But like said before, to get a better answer update your question with more info.

Comment: It's hard to know how the template does it if we don't know what the template is

Comment: My point is it seems like he has a website that he would update as normal and somehow the template magically produces a mobile version for him as well, without him having to create it.

Comment: The website he is working on is budgetwebsitesolutions.co.uk

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
        href="shetland.css" />
  [1]: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/
  [2]: http://www.modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really give you more help than a few links to examples that do a similar thing, as your question is pretty vague. Regardless, these should help your understanding of the basics of responsive design. Here's an example of a responsive menu design, which grows/shrinks in a tidy fashion depending on screen size

http://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/ysblx

and here's an interesting article going into further detail on the matter:

http://css-tricks.com/responsive-menu-concepts/

another website with some examples on handling resizing:

http://thinkmobilefirst.net/nav/

In fact css-tricks also has responsive design on it's actual site as well! So you could always view that as another example. Without further information in your question, I can't really offer more than my own guess knowledge of what you're after & a few google searches on the matter.